# SSIS Package Runs Manually but Not from SQL Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job

I get series of Errors when SSIS package (deployed in file system) Executed from SQL Job , but same package works fine if executed manually.

First Error :

> Directing the row to the error output failed with error code
>   0x80070057.

Second Error :

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on
>   component "OLE DB Destination" (86) failed with error code 0xC0209022
>   while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (99). The identified
>   component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
>   specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the
>   Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.

and then :

> Setting the end of rowset for the buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020

And then:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on
>     returned error code 0xC0209017.  The component
>   returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
>   The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the
>   error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Not getting any clue what could be the issue.

Same package was working fine few days earlier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Almost impossible to tell just from the error messages (without your package, data, etc.), but given "Setting the end of rowset for the buffer failed" and the fact that the package worked fine days earlier, that screams of a data issue, likely at the end of the file or row.  Check your data, and also make sure that the package version deployed to the server is identical to the one you're able to run successfully manually.

Comment: Is the error output a file or folder, in this case?  Are you using a proxy account to execute the package, and if so, has it been modified?

Comment: Did you deploy it right? Otherwise doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue and done the below one.

In SQL SERVER CONNECTION PROPERTY, try to set the 'NO COUNT' option to 'OFF' and see is that fix your issue?

[image]